# Formulation of linear problem

Tags: linear-programming

I'd like to ask you how to formulate this problem as linear problem (equations)?

Marie wants to buy oranges and apples. She has to buy at least 5 oranges and the number of oranges has to be less than 2 times number of apples. One orange weights 150 g and one apple weights 100 g. She can't take more than 3600 g of fruits. One orange costs 70 cents, one apple costs 90 cents. How much she can spend the most?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall try to go from your words to equations and I shall note $O$ the number of oranges and $A$ the number of apples Marie will buy.

Your first sentence says that Maries has to by at least $5$ oranges; this translates to $$O \geq 5$$ It also says that the number of oranges has to be less than $2$ times number of apples; this translates to $$O \lt 2 \times  A$$ Now the total weight of the fruits must be lower than $3600$ grams; similarly, this translates to $$150 \times O + 100  \times A \leq 3600$$ Now, you want that Marie spends all her money and the total price of the fruit is given by $$Cost = 0.70 \times O + 0.90 \times A$$ which you want to maximize, all the previous constraints being satisfied.

Comment: Thank you! So that the standard form with slack variables will be:
$O - s_1 = 5$, $O -2\times A + s_2 = 0$ and $150\times O + 100\times A + s_3 = 3600$?

Comment: @kmaci. You are welcome ! What you wrote is correct. Cheers.